# Exclude permanently IE 9 from the update listing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-update

Hei there, as in the title, I'd like to exclude permanently the IE 9 install from the update list on Windows 7 replacing IE 8. As a web developper i prefer to have a clean and native version of IE8 instead of the emulate version inside IE 9; even with the manual check to install specific items in the update list, I'm always afraid to erroneously include the IE 9 installer.

So is there a way to remove an item from the update list or make it unavailable permanently?

(I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1)

Comment: Microsoft release a tool to block this update years ago.  I would install that.

Comment: I believe you can tell Windows Update to hide updates you're not interested in (if you have it set to always ask you before installing updates).

Comment: @martineau interesting, can you point me in the right direction for this process? I haven't found anything that allow me to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound can you provide me a link for that? I'd prefer a more convenient solution like the one of martineau for this instead of installing a dedicated software/app

Comment: @Gruber - Just search for the tool, you apply it once, and IE9 won't be automatically installed ever.

Comment: In which case you should probably block the IE10 installation too.  There's a tool to do it already available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hide and thereby exclude any update you wish in Microsoft Update. In the screenshot below I've circled in red where you can click to put a check-mark to do this. Afterwards a`Restore Hidden Updates`option should be visible in the left margin.

[image: screenshot of microsoft update window]

**Update:**

You're right, I'm on XP -- however I think you can do the equivalent in Win 7 because of the [comment](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/discussions/102-344861-3455595) shown below in a discussion on TechRepublic about how to [Prevent the automatic delivery of Windows Internet Explorer 9 in Windows 7](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/discussions/102-344861):

[image: screenshot showing comment about hiding the IE9 update on win7]

Comment: Thank you, but your win update look quite differently from mine. Are you using Windows 7? looks like XP to me, nonetheless I guess it will be useful for other users!

Comment: @Gruber: [Steps for Win7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/24376-windows-update-hide-restore-hidden-updates.html).

Comment: aaaw that's it! Right click --> hide, meh sometimes can be so easy that you simply pass over it, thank you!